# Flutter & Firebase stream from certain type of data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make an app with flutter and firebase. At the moment I have listings from the app displayed using a stream builder. I have a stream that displays all of the postings

```
Stream _streamAll = Firestore.instance.collection('postings').snapshots();
```

but I'm just trying to display postings by their categories. Two categories are Arts & Culture and Sporting Events. I tried displaying only postings that were in the Sporting Events category like this

```
 Stream _sportsStream = Firestore.instance.collection('postings').where(
  'type' == 'Sporting Events').snapshots();
```

but get this error

════════ (2) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath].
 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart':
Failed assertion: line 131 pos 12: 'field is String || field is FieldPath' User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was:
Scaffold [link to file where the problem occurs]

Was hoping someone knew the fix to this.

Categories are in my Firestore consle like this:

Field: type
Type: string
Value: [myCategoryName]

[image from firebase console on what I'm trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NptQ.png)

Thank you

Comment: what results are you getting?

Comment: ════════ (2) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath].
'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart':
Failed assertion: line 131 pos 12: 'field is String || field is FieldPath'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold [link to where the problem occurs]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('postings').where(
  'type' == 'Sporting Events').snapshots();
```

Into this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('postings').where(
  'type', isEqualTo: 'Sporting Events').snapshots();
```

You cannot use `==` inside the `where()` method, instead use `isEqualTo`

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/query.dart#L123